# Javascript analysis fail for .js files containing ES7 Decorators

Tags: sonarqube, ecmascript-2016

I'm currently using Babel (the Javascript transpiler) which allows me to use the future syntax now. I'm using the decorator functionality (https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators). However when I run analysis on that code, SonarQube throws the following error:

[09:19:43] 09:19:43.693 ERROR - Unable to parse file: /...../my-form.js
09:19:43.693 ERROR - Parse error at line 10 column 1:

```
1: import {View, Component, Inject, NgScope} from 'app/app';
...
9: 
10: @Component({
    ^
11:   selector: 'my-form'
12: })
13: @View({
14:   template: myTemplate
15: })
```

Will this be covered soon by the Javascript plugin (or at least skipped by the parser but allowing it to continue processing of the file)?.
Is there a way to file a JIRA issue for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SonarQube user group:

> Regarding the support of the decorator construction, it will not be supported by the JavaScript plugin as long as it will not be part of the ECMAScript Standard.
>   Moreover when the JavaScript plugin is not able to parse a file the analysis should not fail, it should succeed but no issue will be reported on the unparsed file.

**However** there is already a JIRA ticket where you can vote up to show them the need for this feature.

[JIRA - Support experimental JavaScript features](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-699)